# When using a Hand Saw (or Hack saw), Dust hides line

Tags: hand-tools

Whenever I start cutting a piece of wood with either a handsaw or hacksaw (i.e. manual saw), the dust covers the line I drew, thereby making following the line very difficult if not impossible.

I am also wearing a dust mask, so I can't blow the dust away (also to take a deep breath to blow the dust would cause me to inhale dust).

What are solutions to this? Cheap and expensive?

Comment: is your blade installed backward?  .... cheap solution: fan .... expensive solution: radial arm saw

Comment: Shop vacuum and a clamp?

Comment: 1. Draw a very heavy line.  2.  Inhale through your nose and blow through your mouth to clear the line. I have found that a hand saw doesn't fling a lot of dust into the air and so I don't wear a dust mask when using one. 3. What kind of hand saw are you using: a stiff one that cuts on the push or a flexible one that cuts on the pull?

Comment: you could get a Japanese saw; they cut away from you. you can poke a straw though your mask and blow out of that. you can vacuum it up with your other hand. you can cut at an angle so it falls off.

Comment: @dandavis, Japanese saws cut on pull stroke

Comment: I feel like the options are almost literally endless... Do you have any additional requirements that could narrow this down? Otherwise, I feel this is almost the definition of "overly broad."

Answer (score 1):

Painter here.  I stock quality throwaway brushes ([Redtree Fooler](https://www.smsdistributors.com/products/redtree-arroworthy-linzer-fooler-double-thick-chip-brushes?variant=209127408)) and I find them all the time in the wood shop next to saws.

**The woodshop guys use paint brushes to dust off woodwork**.

A chip brush is a "cheapie" natural bristle paint brush. They are ideal for chasing chips.  The 2" width is the most popular amongst the woodworkers and metalworkers.  Expect to pay $1-1.50 retail for generic cheapies.

Being natural bristle, they hate latex paint. They work fine for alkyds, and are ideal for 2-part coatings (LPU) where cleaning the brush is out of the question.  We win awards with em.

Comment: Actually those cheap throw-away brushes are called **chip brushes**, because they are made for sweeping away chips (or sawdust). They definitely aren't any good for painting.

Comment: So *I've* been stealing *their* brushes all this time?  .......... seriously we use them on award-winning paint jobs using $400/gallon LPU marine paint (read: you will not be using the brush a second time).  I squabble with my boss, he likes the McMaster-Carr generics, I like the Foolers (we both paint).  They definitely aren't any good for latex.

Comment: How would one use a brush *while making a cut*?

Comment: @isherwood either helper or 1-handed tool, or pause.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it but maybe if you put the wood piece at angle, it will move the dust little bit bellow/to the side of the line because of the vibration so you will be able to see at least couple mm...
If you try this, tell me if it worked I am curious myself...

Answer (score 1):

Larry Haun does a little work with a hand saw at the end of a section in this video from 4:45 to 11:45. In between he shows how to make cuts in framing lumber without drawing lines. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BuQ9RDXu10

Answer (score 1):

*Make your cut somewhere that doesn't require a mask.*

Seriously, woodworkers rely on their breath constantly. Taking away that utility would seriously hamper my productivity. Find a workspace with cleaner air. The bit of dust that's generated by the cut isn't usually a health concern.

Comment: Yeah as I was answering your comment, I was thinking this same thing.  Why are you using a dust mask for *hand sawing*?  Dust masks are for power tools and wood isn't even particularly toxic.  A hand saw just won't raise enough dust to matter.